# Windows Vista authorization issues

Tags: windows-vista, authorization

I have a Dell XPS M1530 notebook. It came with Windows Vista pre-installed, yet recently I get some messages saying that I don't have an authentic Windows OS.

What does this mean, and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

It could be pretty much anything from a bad patch down to corrupt system files.

Easy things to check- Go to an elevated command prompt and type SFC /verifyonly (or do the full check and replace if you are confident) and see if there are any system files that are wrong.

Do you have any errors or warnings in the event log that give any better information?

If you haven't fiddled around with system files or reinstalled the OS, I would contact Dell or Microsoft directly. You paid, it's there problem!

Comment: +1 have to agree with the last part - I would contact Dell and let them deal with it.

Comment: phone MS and talk to a representative. explain the situation, the problem occurs quite frequently and they gladly provide help. +1

Comment: @ezwi the problem is with MS' activation server, nothing Dell can do about. their solution would be a factory default system restore.